# Hide the Week Start Day

Tags: config

Is it possible to hide the **week start day** on the 'Account' tab?

I'm about to import 400+ members and don't want to confuse them with this unnecessary setting (from their perspective).

Thanks in advance.

Adam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this using the [CP CSS plugin](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) from Lindsey DiLoreto.

Install the plugin then add the following custom css:

```
#weekStartDay-field { display: none; }
```

Note that this will hide the field for all users, including you.